# var/cache folder permission for prestashop 1.7.6.1 install process on a Mac local Server

Tags: caching, homebrew, var, prestashop-1.7, macos-mojave

While trying to install prestashop Version 1.7.6.1 at my Mac set as local server installed by Homebrew with virtual host , i get this message:

> We can't start installation :(
>   PrestaShop installation needs to write critical files in the folder var/cache. Please review the permissions on your server.
>   You can contact your web host provider to fix theses requirements

In between the things that i tryed

```
chmod 777 /var/cache
```

Also Changed ownership to my user and _www ,www , wheel groups respectively with no luck with any of them

```
sudo chown nameofmysuer:_www /var/cache
```

This is the permission at / for var
[image: permission for the root of /var]

Before you say that /var folder is not with right permission look at my failed try to change it to 777
[image: Insfructuous try to give 777 to the /var folder]

Permission for  /var/cache were succesfully changed, please note that i also tryed with some other groups like wheel and www groups , nevertheless any other combination is welcome.

[image: permisions for /var/cache]

Answer (score 1):

little late answer, but, you had changed permission for wrong directory.

try below command to change permission for right directory:

```
$ pwd
/var/www

$ ll

drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:42 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:52 example.com/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:42 html/

$ sudo chown -R www-data:  /var/www/example.com/

$ ll

drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:42 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096  4월 18 12:52 example.com/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096  4월 18 12:42 html/
```